# Does a Canadian citizen need a visa for a stopover in New Zealand?

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, canadian-citizens, new-zealand, stopovers

I have a 14-hour layover in New Zealand before I have a connecting flight to Melbourne, Australia. Do I need a visa if I wanted to leave the airport and go to a hotel? I am a Canadian citizen with the Canadian passport.

Answer (score 8):

Canada is on New Zealand’s list of visa waiver countries. Canadian citizens don’t need a visa to enter New Zealand for short visits of up  up to 3 months https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/transit-visa

Edit Oct2022: For visa-waiver countries like Canada, an NZeTA (New Zealand Electronic Travel Authority) is now needed before travelling.

Comment: According to the page stated, above, it seems that if you leave the airport, you'll need a Visa: "With this visa you can
Pass through Auckland International airport as a transit passenger – you’ll need to stay in the airport’s transit area at all times."

Comment: They do, however, now require an NZETA: https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/nzeta

Comment: @lambshaanxy Thank you, I’ve updated my 2018 answer